# Splitting and wrapping words inside a textarea like YouTube tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create something similar to YouTube videos tags function where you typ a tag and split it on a comma then it gets some styling and cannot be changed again only removed.

I have a pretty basic example but have some problems with some functions like,

I don't know how to remove the comma at the end, I tried slice but with no luck.
Also I want to prevent the div's from being removed with backspace.
And I want to display the cursor line again after splitting a word, now you have to type before it reappears.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jf10gu02/2/)

```
<div id='textarea' contenteditable></div>

$('#textarea').on('keyup', function(){
  var input = $(this).html();
  var lastChar = input[input.length -1];

  if(lastChar == ','){
    $(this).contents().last().wrapAll("<div class='contentWrapper' contenteditable='false'/>");
    console.log($(this).contents().last().html());
  }
});

#textarea {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font-family: Roboto, Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans,Arial,sans-serif;
    height: 120px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 234px;
    display: block;
}

.contentWrapper{
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #B0AEAE;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Why do you reinvent the wheel? You can use chosen js plugin that it does all for you. https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ || https://select2.github.io/

Comment: Here is my choice: https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Comment: @DanielCheung better than mine, allows custom tags. Perfect!

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude thanks, did not know about the plugin I tried searching but didn't know what to call it

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Yep, and that's why I'd recommend this one. I make mine look like those pentagon price tags ;) I also think it is easy to use this to do twitter typeahead, although speaking the truth, I haven't explored Chosen yet.

Comment: Chosen is perfect to replace native `<select>` elements, and allows you to work as you want with no limitations.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Wow! Never knew that before, but I've written my own little jQuery function that converts `<select>` into Bootstrap dropdowns.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I only see select box options, what do I need for a text area with user input?